# Automatically get Ray head node IP address

Tags: kubernetes, ray

I deployed a Ray cluster on an AKS cluster.
To run my applications leveraging the Ray cluster, currently I'm deploying each of my applications as a classic k8s Deployment object and connecting to the Ray cluster using

```
ray.init(address="<head-node-ip:10001")
```

The problem is that I'm manually inserting the head node IP by looking at the head node ip through `kubectl describe pod head-node-pod`. Is there a way to get it automatically ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what (headless) Service resources are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be leveraging on **Kubernetes services** and use the **DNS instead of IP**.

so in your case, the DNS would be `head-node-svc.your-namespace.svc.cluster.local` where head-node-svc is your new service associated with head node pod, your-namespace is your namespace where the pods and services are created, svc stays there as it is and cluster.local is your cluster domain.